# I need a whole new MetaMask account, with a whole new seed phrase

Tags: metamask, accounts

No one can seem answer this for me. My old business has my seed phrase. this never bothered me b/c there was never more than a $100 in there. Now it does. How to set up a new account? Not a new wallet, but a whole new account. I can't find it anywhere

Comment: Did you try installing Metamask and creating a new account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `metamask` extension and then install it again. This time, when you open it, you will see this:

[image]

Choose "**Create a Wallet**" and you can set up a new Wallet with a completely new seed phrase there.

After doing this, transfer all your funds from your original wallet to this one and do not share your new seed phrase with anyone. Store your seed phrase offline in a secure place.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood your question, it states that you want to create a new account with new phrases in existing wallet and you don't want your previous business to access it.

It is not possible to create a new account with a new seed phrase within the same wallet. Each wallet is tied to a single seed phrase. So creating account is tied to that wallet. If someone has access to your wallet seed phrases, he has access to your all accounts that you have created in that wallet. accounts are tied to private keys not to seed phrases.